# Using API key with Freebase

Tags: php, freebase, api-key

I'm hitting the user limit of freebase while reading out information. It certainly has to do with the fact I don't use my API-Key which I generated in the Google API console.

But I don't have a clue where I've got to use the API Key? With google maps it's in the link to the javascript source.

Where can I add the API key for freebase?

I'm using this query to retrieve my information from freebase:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query={....}
```

Comment: Have you got logins for freebase.com?

Comment: Nope, I just activate the api key in https://code.google.com/apis/console/ And as it is a server to server call i prefer a API key solution of some kind. Just like the google maps api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [docs here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#WhatIsKey).

The relevant section is:

> An API key is a unique key that you generate using the Console. When
>   your application needs to call an API that's enabled in this project,
>   the application passes this key into all API requests as a
>   **key=API_key** parameter. Use of this key does not require any user action or consent, does not grant access to any account information,
>   and is not used for authorization.